# jQuery getting data attribute and setting correct selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to jQuery and think I'm close to what I'm needing.

I need to get the value from the data-status and then set the correct select option and selected.

```js
// set default status
$('.column.small').each(function() {
  var $currentStatus = $(this);
  var optionStatus = $currentStatus.data('status');
  // u = updated
  // n = new
  if (optionStatus == 'u') {
    foundStatus = $currentStatus.find('select option');
    if ($(foundStatus).val() == 'u') {
      $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
    } else if ($(foundStatus).val() == 'n') {
      $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-status="u" class="column small grey" selected="selected">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select id="PC_Row_1_Status" name="PC_Row_1_Status" ccm-passed-value="u" class="form-control">
      <option value="u" selected="selected">Updated</option>
      <option value="n">New</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div data-status="u" class="column small grey" selected="selected">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select id="PC_Row_2_Status" name="PC_Row_2_Status" ccm-passed-value="u" class="form-control">
      <option value="u" selected="selected">Updated</option>
      <option value="n">New</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div data-status="n" class="column small grey" selected="selected">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select id="PC_Row_3_Status" name="PC_Row_3_Status" ccm-passed-value="u" class="form-control">
      <option value="u" selected="selected">Updated</option>
      <option value="n">New</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div data-status="n" class="column small grey" selected="selected">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select id="PC_Row_4_Status" name="PC_Row_4_Status" ccm-passed-value="u" class="form-control">
      <option value="u" selected="selected">Updated</option>
      <option value="n">New</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should simply use `.val()` method to set the value of element.

```
// set default status
$('.column.small').each(function() {
      var $currentStatus = $(this);
      var optionStatus = $currentStatus.data('status');
      $currentStatus.find('select').val(optionStatus);
});
```

```js
// set default status
$('.column.small').each(function() {
  var $currentStatus = $(this);
  var optionStatus = $currentStatus.data('status');
  $currentStatus.find('select').val(optionStatus);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-status="u" class="column small grey" selected="selected">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select id="PC_Row_1_Status" name="PC_Row_1_Status" ccm-passed-value="u" class="form-control">
      <option value="u" selected="selected">Updated</option>
      <option value="n">New</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div data-status="u" class="column small grey" selected="selected">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select id="PC_Row_2_Status" name="PC_Row_2_Status" ccm-passed-value="u" class="form-control">
      <option value="u" selected="selected">Updated</option>
      <option value="n">New</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div data-status="n" class="column small grey" selected="selected">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select id="PC_Row_3_Status" name="PC_Row_3_Status" ccm-passed-value="u" class="form-control">
      <option value="u" selected="selected">Updated</option>
      <option value="n">New</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div data-status="n" class="column small grey" selected="selected">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select id="PC_Row_4_Status" name="PC_Row_4_Status" ccm-passed-value="u" class="form-control">
      <option value="u" selected="selected">Updated</option>
      <option value="n">New</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i was going a long way around wasn't i haha thanks mate